# Nested REST API resource not found

Tags: rest, http, response, http-status-codes

This feels like what should be a very common question but I cannot find anything related to it. I am working on a 'REST' API with nested / sub-resources

```
GET /user/1
GET /user/1/friends
```

I believe by now it is fairly widely accepted that if user 1 does not exist, a `404` response is expected from the first URL (with a body response detailing the *Resource* is not found).

However for the second URL, if user 1 does exist, but has no friends, what should be returned?

- 404 (feels weird)
- 200 with a body of an empty result
- Something else

Note; I am **not** saying this is the best REST implementation; this API has been inherited. Personally I would do something like

```
GET /friends?user=1
```

which would return a 200 empty array, but I cannot change the nested resource API path URLs, just the responses.

Also I realize REST depends more on the response body content (hyperlink media), so this is more about clean API design, but I still think the HTTP response codes fall into REST.

Answer (score 1):

In the request for `GET /user/1/friends`,

User 1 does not exist: `404`, the user does not exist, so sub-resource/collection also does not exist.

User 1 does exist: `200`, The sub-resource/collection being queried does exist, it is empty.

Query on `/users/1/nonExistentCollection`: `404`, the collection does not exist.